# Splitting text into lines and then splitting into characters and print into tr,td

Tags: jquery

I want to split text into lines first with jquery and then split each line into its characters(I get from the text file).
Row layout will not be broken.
I want to print each line in tr and each character in td(including spaces).
I have this text:

TANJA   NANI      A   ADEBCDECDDECDBABABABABABABABABABABABABABAZ  ADAD
HEPPO   CEPPO     BCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC      CCCCC  CCCCCCCCCC
MERC    DARK      A   ADEBCDECDDECDBABABABABABABABABABABABA   BAB

How should the for loop or each loop be correct?
I tried this code.

```
jQuery.get('AA.txt', function (data) {

   var lines = data.split("\r\n");

  for(var i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++){
     $('#table').append('<tr></tr>');       
     var lin =lines[i].split(/(?!$)/u);

      for(var k = 0 ; k < lin.length; k++){
       $('#table tr').append('<td>'+ lin[k] + '</td>');
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: What's going wrong with your current code?

Comment: The loop in the code first takes all the lines, then continues the loop by decreasing it, completing the loop with the last single line.

Comment: Could be your carriage return, try with `\r` or `\n` and see if the result is different. I have an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bcnzhfs/1/) which works with `\n` only (granted I used a variable for your text instead of jq get)

Comment: Update: This works better if you target `.last()` (`$('#table tr').last().append`) on your `tr` elements in jQuery ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0dh16jnt/1/))

Comment: Can O' Spam,
thank you for your solution,  it worked  'last()'